# How inspectlet and other services store user video sessions?

Tags: webrtc, inspectlet

I was wondering how the services like http://www.inspectlet.com/ does store the video sessions. By the looks I don't think it's a webRTC implementation. What i was able to figure out that there is active express socket which is making communication but in that case they will have to store the page and track all the events from DOM. Just wanted to confirm that this is the approach they are following.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the event listeners on the page, it looks like there are a lot of bindings. For example, the `<body>` has `scroll`, `keyup`, and `change` events bound to a function. I'm sure it also has `mousemove`, `mouseclick`, etc. All of this is likely stored in a Javascript variable (object, probably) and then AJAXed every so often to http://hn.inspectlet.com/adddata with the data parameters. Here is a sample of what is being sent:

```
http://hn.inspectlet.com/adddata?d=mr,212941,46,337,46,1277)mr,213248,163,498,163,1438)mr,213560,144,567,144,1507)mr,213873,138,240,138,1180)mr,214188,169,184,169,1124)mr,214504,158,520,158,1460)mr,214816,231,487,231,1427)mr,215130,329,197,329,1137)mr,215444,894,289,894,1229)mr,215755,903,295,903,735)s,215755,440,0)&w=259769975&r=494850609&sd=1707&sid=1660474937&pad=3&dn=dn&fadd=false&oid=99731212&lpt=212629
```

Comment: But how they are maintaining the page state, that is bugging me. They download the page and maintain the state of the page or cache it on server.Any idea will be helpful and thanks for responding.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. If they're constantly collecting environment data and sending that off to the server every second, they wouldn't necessarily need to know what content is on the page or what has changed. I'm not entirely sure this concept would work on a dynamically generated page because they would have to send the entire page contents onload, then user events and content changes every ping. User events take up little data. Page HTML does not. Plus they'd lose any element bindings and such.

Comment: We can see that they are sending packets in the form of gif... So how page data can be converted in a gif??

Comment: They say here https://www.inspectlet.com/docs/faq that states "Inspectlet's screen capture is a component of the code that works by recording all the events that take place in the browser such as keystrokes, mouse movements, scrolling, clicking, and then sends this data (which is only bytes in size) to our servers. Once we receive this data, we compile a screen capture by overlaying the events onto the visitor's page." So likely when they send the data the time is also take into account - then just just playit all together on their end - no magic.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in Adam's answer, they track many events in the page and send them either via a websocket or post/get request (XHR) to their servers.

I am not sure what inspectlet does specifically, but in general, such a solution will need to follow the below general steps:

When the page is fully loaded (hook on DOMContentLoaded probably) they will send the page data to the server. Then they also hook on MutationObserver in order to track all changes to the DOM in the page, so when something changes dynamically, the tracking script can 'record' it and send it to the server.

The SaaS application in turn, will have a player that will parse all this raw data and then play it back, this will usually require using some virtual file system for assests (images, css, scripts) and handling js scripts to not post back again (replay xhr will have bad results for tracked websites) but play back the mutations as they were captured (recorded)

In regards of data HTML pages compress really well, especially when you can make assumptions about the data (since you know its html) - so yes, they actually cache a lot (similar to what google does in that regards, but google does it for the entire web, not just 'customers')

The DOM Mutations will need to be stored as well. This is up to the algorithm, it can either be stored as plain text or using a smarter data model, storing them in plain text is obviously not the cost effective solution.

The above is an abstraction, there are *many* edge cases to handle in order to implement such a solution as well as a lot of mathematical and algorithmic thinking in regards of heatmaps to make them accurate.

Comment: Do you know how it can be possible to send the entire page to the server? On some webpages there are a huge amount of data...

Comment: one word: gzip, but HTML can compress relatively good with more naive compression methods as well. Yes - there are pages that can get to a really large size even gzippped - i would assume that these solution will also have a mechanism to understand if the page needs to be sent at all - after all, a single version of the page is usually enough.

Answer (score 2):

So after a long search was able to find a new promising solution on the block, which solves all the complex parts in building such service. It is still under development but it solves the problem. Below is the link to it,

> https://www.rrweb.io/
>
> https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb